# Java AWT Graphics - Interpolate Shapes with subpixel accuracy

Tags: java, graphics, awt, graphics2d

I'm working on a project where I need an animation of balls moving on an ellipse (e.g. a circumference). At the moment, I'm drawing it all on a `JPanel`, by overriding the `paintComponent()` method, and the moving effect comes from repainting it at a fixed rate, and changing the position of the "balls".

It all works good enough, except that the balls seem to move in a "laddery" way, and not smoothly. Since it's a problem between the drawings, I suppose messing with `RenderingHints` will lead nowhere.

An SSCCE of the issue (From the test, it might not seem that noticeable, but when you have more than 100 balls moving, it looks really weird):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SSCCE {

    private static long dt;
    private static JPanel animationPanel = createAnimationPanel();

    private static JPanel createAnimationPanel() {
        return new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                
                int w = this.getWidth();
                int h = this.getHeight();
                Point center = new Point(w / 2, h / 2);

                // Drawing circumference.
                int radius = 80;
                int x = center.x - radius;
                int y = center.y - radius;
                g2d.drawOval(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2);

                // Drawing ball.
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                int ballWidth = 20;
                double rad = Math.toRadians((dt / ((radius * 2) / 8.0)));
                int xPos = (int) (center.x - (Math.cos(rad) * radius) - (ballWidth / 2));
                int yPos = (int) (center.y - (Math.sin(rad) * radius) - (ballWidth / 2));
                g2d.fillOval(xPos, yPos, ballWidth, ballWidth);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.getContentPane().add(animationPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setEnabled(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.requestFocus();
        });

        Thread updateThread = new Thread(() -> {
            long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) { // I don't actually use "while (true)", but it doesn't matter since it's a test.
                dt = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime;
                animationPanel.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "Update Thread");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(updateThread::start);
    }
}
```

So in conclusion, I thought that maybe I could interpolate the positions into subpixel level, and in some way draw the ball "between the pixels", in a way similar to how an Anti-alias effect works... Is it possible? If not, is there any workaround?

Comment: Swing's not thread safe

Comment: Wouldn't running it inside an `invokeLater()` call fix it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're starting the `Thread` on the EDT, not running it within the EDT - and since it's just a `while-loop`, if it did run in the EDT, it'd block and nothing would update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is related to the truncating of the `double` value to `int`

```
int xPos = (int) (center.x - (Math.cos(rad) * radius) - (ballWidth / 2));
int yPos = (int) (center.y - (Math.sin(rad) * radius) - (ballWidth / 2));
```

Instead, you should be making use the `double` values.  In this case, you can simply `translate` the `Graphics2D` API, for example...

```
// Drawing ball.
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
int ballWidth = 20;
double rad = Math.toRadians((dt / ((radius * 2) / 8.0)));
double xPos = (center.x - (Math.cos(rad) * radius) - (ballWidth / 2));
double yPos = (center.y - (Math.sin(rad) * radius) - (ballWidth / 2));

if (theActualDot == null) {
   theActualDot = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, ballWidth, ballWidth);
}

g2d.translate(xPos, yPos);
g2d.fill(theActualDot);
```

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    private static long dt;
    private static JPanel animationPanel = createAnimationPanel();

    private static JPanel createAnimationPanel() {
        return new JPanel() {

            private Shape theActualDot;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                int w = this.getWidth();
                int h = this.getHeight();
                Point center = new Point(w / 2, h / 2);

                // Drawing circumference.
                int radius = 80;
                int x = center.x - radius;
                int y = center.y - radius;
                g2d.drawOval(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2);

                // Drawing ball.
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                int ballWidth = 20;
                double rad = Math.toRadians((dt / ((radius * 2) / 8.0)));
                double xPos = (center.x - (Math.cos(rad) * radius) - (ballWidth / 2));
                double yPos = (center.y - (Math.sin(rad) * radius) - (ballWidth / 2));

                if (theActualDot == null) {
                    theActualDot = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, ballWidth, ballWidth);
                }

                g2d.translate(xPos, yPos);
                g2d.fill(theActualDot);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.getContentPane().add(animationPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setEnabled(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.requestFocus();

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dt = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime;
                    animationPanel.repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        });
    }
}
```